# Core Data not saving after using Firebase to fetch value - swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked around different posts trying to put together reasons why saving core data isn't working for me.

My entity name is **[ImportantData]** with 2 attributes's **[attribute1] [attribute2]** set at Strings (either "yes" or "no").

I use firebase to see if a value has changed. Firebase name is **["FirebaseName"]** with child **["firebaseChild"]**

The below func is called in **'performFetchWithCompletionHandler'** in AppDelegate.

```
var importantData = [ImportantData]()
var refFetchWorking: DatabaseReference!


func isFetchWorking() {
refFetchWorking = Database.database().reference().child("FirebaseName")
refFetchWorking?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot } in
     let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
     let fetch = dict["firebaseChild"] as! String
     let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistantContainer.viewContext

     let data = ImportantData(context:context)
     let attribute1 = data.attribute1
     let attribute2 = data.attribute2

  do {
      self.attribute1 = try context.fetch(ImportantData.fetchRequest())
      print(attribute1!, attribute2!, "fetch")
   } catch {
       print("fail fetched"
     }

  if fetch != "closed" {
      data.setValue("yes", forKey: "attribute1"
      data.setValue("yes", forKey: "attribute2"

   do {
        try context.save()
    print(attribute1!, attribute2!, "test")
} catch {
 print("error after test"
}

} else {
print ("is closed!")
}

do { context.save()
  print(attribute1!, attribute2!, "after save")
} catch {
  print("error saving)
}
})
}
```

the NSLog is printing:

"no no fetch"

"no no test"

"no no after save"

but fetch != "closed"

any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You only have one context in the app right ?

Comment: Correct. Context meaning I'm only pulling one thing from the AppDelegate?

Comment: I think may be you context is nil. Please check !